# Sync with Azure cloud database systems

Tags: mysql, postgresql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

We have requirement to sync on-premises database with Azure cloud database systems in real time after database migration to the cloud.

Here are the database system

Sql Server --> Will be migrated to Azure SQL.

PostgreSQL --> Will be migrated to Azure VM (IAAS).

MYSQL --> Will be migrated to Azure MySQL.

DB2 --> Will be migrated to Azure VM (IAAS).

Please let me know the options through which i can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

There was an announcement at Build that covers some of this, take a look here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-database-migration-service-announcement-at-build/

Basically it offers SQL > Azure SQL or VM + SQL and MySql > Azure SQL or VM + SQL.

So there is no easy way to achieve this. You would have to use a separate migration\replication techniques for those DB's. And that question is too broad to be covered here.

Comment: Thanks! for the detail . I was thinking of option for Oracle golden gate tool to set up the replication between on premise and cloud database. For sql as source its possible to set up the replication with sql cloud  (ref link: https://devjef.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/setting-up-replication-from-on-premise-sql-server-to-azure-sql-db/) 

If you can think of any other tool or service within Azure that i can leverage to achieve this sync operation do let me know

Comment: well, that tool allows to replicate oracle stuff, not postgre. and it allows mysql only to sql, so you can't benefit frmo that. and sql to sql was possible long time ago. and if this answers your questions you should accept it as an aswer @user1941025

Comment: Can this sync operation be implemented using Microsoft Sync framework SDK for database other than SQL database.??